# Terraform | Error "transport is closing" when "terraform apply" after upgrading to 0.12

Tags: terraform

```
Terraform v0.12.7
+ provider.aws v2.25.0
+ provider.null v2.1.2
+ provider.template v2.1.2
```

Hello, when I try run `terraform apply` after upgrading to 0.12 I get error:

```
module.elasticsearch.module.ec2.aws_instance.this[0]: Modifying... [id=i-075090c94e5117ce3]
module.elasticsearch.module.ec2.aws_instance.this[1]: Modifying... [id=i-01fddbae2487e2573]

Error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing



Error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing


Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
```

Also I found next errors in logs:

```
[DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=/home/user/env-beta/.terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v2.25.0_x4 pid=25405 error="exit status 2"
2019/08/29 14:47:18 [DEBUG] module.elasticsearch.module.ec2.aws_instance.this[1]: apply errored, but we're indicating that via the Error 
pointer rather than returning it: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019/08/29 14:47:18 [DEBUG] module.elasticsearch.module.ec2.aws_instance.this[0]: apply errored, but we're indicating that via the Error 
pointer rather than returning it: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
2019/08/29 14:47:18 [ERROR] module.elasticsearch.module.ec2: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost, err: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019/08/29 14:47:18 [ERROR] module.elasticsearch.module.ec2: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019/08/29 14:47:18 [ERROR] module.elasticsearch.module.ec2: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost, err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
2019/08/29 14:47:18 [ERROR] module.elasticsearch.module.ec2: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
```

And I notice strange thing, terraform wants add to this ec2 `credit_specification {}` but instance type is i3.large...

Maybe someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in terraform aws ec2 module, last working version is 2.5.0